# Requests.get() gets stuck on connect

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I'm trying to make a simple get request using `requests`

```
import requests

def main():
    content = requests.get("https://google.com")
    print(content.status_code)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I'm running this on Linux, version 17.10.
Python version: either 2.7 or 3.6 (tried both).

The code gets stuck in running, it doesn't timeout or anything.

After I stop it, based on the callstack, it gets stuck at:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
```

Answer (score 1):

I just ran your code on Python console and it returned `200`. I am Running Python 3.6.7, Ubuntu 18.04.

It may be the case that your computer cannot connect to google.com for a very long time, you should pass `timeout` parameter along with `try except`

Use the following code:

```
import requests

def main():
    success = False
    while success==False:
        try:
            content = requests.get("https://google.com", timeout=5)
            success=True
        except:
            pass
    print(content.status_code)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If there is a temporary problem with your network connection, this code snippet gurantees a proper response.

Comment: Resurrecting an old post, I know. But I have to say, this snippet is useful.